# How to call .xqy page from other .xqy page in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Can I call a .xqy page from another .xqy page in Marklogic ?

Comment: What in this situation is an XQuery page?  Are you talking about HTML pages generated with XQuery?  Are you talking about importing a library module from a main module containing reusable code?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to execute another .xqy, but the most obvious is probably by using `xdmp:invoke`. That calls the .xqy, waits for its results and returns them on the spot in your code. You can also call a single function using the combination `xdmp:function` and `xdmp:apply`. You could also mess around with `xdmp:eval`, but that is usually a last resort.

Another strategy could be to use `xdmp:http-get`, but then the execution runs in a different transaction, so would always commit. You would also need to know the url of the other .xqy, which need some knowledge about whether, and how url are rewritten in the app server (not by default).

Running other .xqy without waiting for results is also possible with `xdmp:spawn`. Particularly usefull for dispatching heavy load of for instance content processing. Dispatching batches of 100 to 1000 docs is quite common. Keep an eye on the task queue size though..

HTH!

Comment: If you do get into `xdmp:spawn` territory, https://github.com/mblakele/presta provides some utility functions that may be useful.

Comment: Don't forget xdmp:redirect-response() for a simple HTTP redirect to the other URL.